# Lambda expression for flattening

Tags: c#

```
Class A
{

}

Class B: A
{

}

Class C: A
{
   B children;
}
```

I have a collection of A's with both B and C members within it.

For example

```
collection  A
             -B
             -B
             -C
               -B
               -B
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
B
B
B
B
```

I need to extract a collection of all B types from it using lambda expression. Ideas?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am new to c# and have tried using select many but unable to understand how to get it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can see that you are still a little new and just wanted to give you a couple pointers: First, when posting on SO, be sure to include in your original post (OP) any code or things that you have tried. It is okay to say that you are new to a language, as well. I upvoted your question because this is a difficult task for someone new to C# to solve, and I do not think that the post was deserving of a -3 score. Just remember to include those details in your OPs in the future, and you'll do fine. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like that.

First, get elements of your list which are B.

Then, union with elements of your list which are C, and select their children (which is a B)

```
var list = yourList.OfType<B>()
           .Union(yourList.OfType<C>().Select(x => x.children);
```

But your sample is not clear (or not right with your pseudo-model) : children is a single property, or a collection ?

If it's a collection, use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

Comment: What if the depth is more than 2?

Comment: @Servy - refer to the OP; the depth should never be greater than two

Comment: @Servy I may have missed something, but how could that happen with this structure ?

Comment: Ultimately, that doesn't matter. This shows *how* to solve the problem, even if in the end the application is slightly different.

Comment: @Servy from what I saw in your answer, you assert that this is a tree structure. I don't see what makes you think that with the given code and sample...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Well, two factors, one, the given output shown looks to have a depth of 3, not two, and second, I mistakenly assumed that C : B, not A.  As it is the given hierarchy is very...weird.  I assumed it was a more sensible class structure.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is SelectMany.

http://pastebin.com/ZMD0NLZK

This is a simple demo I made a while back to demonstrate the difference between Select and SelectMany.

EDIT: After further looking, it looks like what you really want may be `.OfType<B>()`

Comment: 1) This doesn't work with an unknown depth, rather only with a depth of two.

Comment: I've given him the tools he needs to solve the problem. In retrospect, there's now a better answer. Even so, it's not a wrong answer, it just requires him to put the pieces together.

Comment: Not really, no.  In fact, solving the problem of traversing a tree is quite a bit more involved than just using `SelectMany`.  In fact, the best solutions I've seen don't use it at all.  And given that it doesn't solve the problem, yes, it is wrong.